# Why is my custom Angular filter not working? (firebase)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to do a custom angular filter for my Ionic + Firebase app. 
My view repeat users from firebase in the "chat" tab. I want to filter it, so it displays only users that one has talked to already. 
I tried to call filter in the view, and it returns error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. When I call it in the controller it displays blank page, no errors. I've been stuck here for a long time.

View:

```
<ion-view view-title="Chats">
  <ion-content> 
     <ion-list >
      <ion-item  class="item-remove-animate item item-thumbnail-left" ng-repeat="user in users | chatfilter" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{ownId}}&ID={{user.id}}" id = "chatlist" >
        <img src="{{user.profilepic}}">
        <h2 id="nameId" ng-model = "nameid"> {{user.name}} <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i></h2>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Filter:

```
  .filter("chatfilter", function (Auth, $firebaseArray){
  return function(items){
    var filteredUsers = []; //I want to push users I've talked to here
    Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
        var ownid = authData.uid;  

        var messages = new Firebase("https://newbuddy.firebaseio.com/messages");
        var i = items.length;
        var latestSnapshot = null;
        var filtered = []; 
        // RegExp will check all messeges references, math those with logged in user's id, and push them to filtered.  
        messages.on('child_added', function(snap) { 
          latestSnapshot = snap.key(); 

          var patt = new RegExp(ownid.toString()); 
          var res = patt.test(latestSnapshot);
          if (res == true) {
            var receiver = latestSnapshot.replace(patt, "");
            filtered.push(receiver);
          }

          // loop will test ids from filtered against all users and push mathes into filtratedUsers.
          for (var j = 0; j < i; j++){

                if (filtered.indexOf(items[j].id) != -1) {
                  filteredUsers.push(items[j].id);
                } 
          }
    })
      return filteredUsers;
  });

 };
})
```

Comment: Your filter function only have one place mentioning the "length" reading, that is reading the length of variable items, so your problem must be failed to pass in the "items" variable. Can you provide your code when you apply filter in views?

Comment: I add pipe "|" and pass the filter name "chatfilter" after user in users repeat. I was wondering if that has something to do with asynchronous data and Firebase.

Comment: Indeed yes, you should not do async-functions inside a filter which may be updated in every angular digest cycle.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to fix that?